# How to log/pinpoint which PHP script uses a lot of memory? Optimization Question

Tags: php, mysql, linux, memory-management, plesk

I wrote a small app that turns out to be using a lot of memory when used by a few users simultaniously. This is leading to some Fatal PHP errors and some mySQL (errcode 12) errors.

My Plesk QoS page shows frequent 'kmemsize' black zone errors.

My question is: What's the best method to monitor PHP script runs to pin-point which .php script is using the most memory? Shell command? Debugger?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I just found that PHP has a function of logging memory usage. http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php
I guess I can make it log time, file, params, and memory usage into a CSV file. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running a [profiler](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+profiler) on it.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds very helpful. I'm looking into it :)

Comment: Alright, so XDebug turned out to be very useful to profile the scripts running. Thanks for the advice.